# Why does Python throw an error when using 'r' before a string with backslashes?

Tags: python

```
print(r"\Michael Jackson  is the best\" )
```

I am expected that python will print it as \Michael Jackson is the best\ ,but python throw me an error.

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 3)
```

However, it is fine for:

```
print(r" Michael Jackson \ is the best" )
```

which gives me  Michael Jackson  is the best

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback